# How to move checkbox to right - Angular CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm a little new to the CSS part and having trouble trying to move my checkbox block to the right and keep the other block on the left.

[My checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dQty.jpg)

[expected checkbox example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WcuV.png)

could you help me please?

My code:

```css
.checkboxpermissions{
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

..modulecheckbox{
  display: grid;
  flex-direction: row;

}
```

```html
<mat-tab label="Permissões">
        <section>
          <h4>Modulos do Grupo de Segurança</h4>
          <hr />
          <form [formGroup]="form">
            <div class="modulecheckbox">
              <div *ngFor="let category of allCategories">
                <h4>{{ category.description }}</h4>
                <mat-checkbox
                  *ngFor="
                    let modules of filterItemsByCategory(
                      selectedAllModules,
                      category
                    )
                  "
                  [value]="modules.id.toString()"
                  >{{ modules.name }}
                  <div class="checkboxpermissions">
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.read"
                      formControlName="read"
                      >Leitura</mat-checkbox
                    >
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.write"
                      formControlName="write"
                      >Escrita</mat-checkbox
                    >
                    <mat-checkbox
                      [(ngModel)]="modules.delete"
                      formControlName="delete"
                      >Exclusão</mat-checkbox
                    >
                  </div>
                </mat-checkbox>
              </div>
             </div>
          </form>
        </section>
        <hr />
      </mat-tab>
```

Comment: Try display: flex instead of display: inline-flex in .checkboxpermissions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flex` instead of `inline-flex` and set the grow property of the first child:

```
.checkboxpermissions {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.checkboxpermissions mat-checkbox:first-child {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

here is an example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-example-rem7zo?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)

Comment: indeed, I recently found about `gap`; this is a more elegant answer than mine, I recommend it

Comment: I tried to do this, but I dont know why its not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to add a grid layout. A simple flex will do, but you need to properly use align to flex end and add a margin to the first column. Maybe this example helps:
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-sound-3w38k9?file=/index.html